# Why is the net charge of a polarized sphere zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, polarization

I have to find the electric field produced by a polarized sphere, with the polarization of $\textbf P(\textbf r) = k \textbf r$. Why do they, in the solution, assume the whole net charge to be zero? How do I know that there's no "additional" charge added to the sphere somehow?

Comment: I think that if it stated that the sphere is polarised with no additional information one can assume that there is no net charge.  Put another way.  If there was additional charge what amount would you assume it to be?

Comment: Can a polarized sphere be treated as a dipole and then calculated?

Comment: @Farcher assumed  it can be calculated somehow...

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis:  A sphere with a uniform polarization (i.e., $\vec{P}$ has the same direction & magnitude everywhere in the object) turns out to produce the same electric field as a point dipole with moment $\vec{p} = \frac{4 \pi}{3} R^3 \vec{P}$.  But this isn't a trivial statement to prove;  it's not true for non-spherical objects, for example.  And it's not applicable here, since $\vec{P}$ doesn't have a constant direction inside the sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you assume that you start with a neutral sphere to begin with. Then suppose you take an electron at the bottom of the sphere and move it to the top. And you do this for a bunch of them. So the top is more negative than the bottom, but the sphere is still neutral, as all you did was move the electrons you already had. You didn't add any additional charges to the sphere, you just rearranged them.

Although, I don't think assuming it has a net charge changes much. It will just add a radial field $\mathbf E(\mathbf r)$ = $\frac {kQ}{r^3}\mathbf r$ ($ Q $ is the net charge) outside of the sphere in addition to what you get assuming that it is uncharged and you have a polarization $\mathbf P(\mathbf r) = k\mathbf r$.